# Column Concatenation

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to concatenate the rows from two/more different columns into one new column ?
Example:

```
 C1     C2      C3
---- + ---- => ----
 a      d       a
 b      e       b 
 c      f       c
                d 
                e
                f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick if you are using T-SQL

```
select C1, C2, a.Chuck
from testa
right join  (select C1 as Chuck from testa UNION ALL select C2 as Chuck from testa) as a  ON a.Chuck = testa.C1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c1 as c3 from T
union 
select c2 as c3 from T
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple union with an order should be enough to achieve your results.
And this will give more consistent results if your source tables aren't correctly ordered.
All be it possibly with worse performance.

```
select c1 as Results
FROM t1
union
select c2 as Results
from t1
order by Results asc
```